# how to load base64 images in Recyclerview without lag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, base64

I've tried below code but when I scroll, it lag too much and it crashes after some time it tries to load images.

```
val productImage = imgStringBase64.convertBitMap()
Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .load(productImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                .into(imgProduct)
```

here's my function,

```
 private fun loadImage(
    imgProduct: ImageView,
    imgString: String
) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val productImage = imgString.convertBitMap()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
                .downsample(DownsampleStrategy.DEFAULT)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .override(300, 300)

            Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .load(productImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                .into(imgProduct)
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the size of the image ? Try compressing the bitmap before loading it.

Comment: image size is approx 60 - 80kb, compress already but still the issue is there when scroll.

Comment: can you share the crash log?

Comment: please upload your model class.

Comment: Actually we fetched list of product from DB and product have image with base64 format, so when we convert it before load using Glide then some time crashed app and when scroll top or bottom its lag too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest coil instead of glide. Its image loading speed is faster. Add diffUtil to your recyclerviews adapter. I am using the extension function below to convert base 64 to bitmap. I don't know what kind of lag you encountered in this case, but give it a try, maybe it will be faster

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["app:imageStr"])
fun ImageView.bindImageStr(
imageStr: String?
) {
imageStr?.let {
    try {
        val imageBytes = Base64.decode(it, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, 
  imageBytes.size)
        setImageBitmap(decodedImage)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This work great!!!!!!!, One doubt I need to ask its not store anything in local disk right?

Comment: @Himani no, its not storing in local disk

Answer (score 0):

It's lag because when you scroll then its converting Base64 to Bitmap every-time for each item.

I will suggest to save Base64 into file and save into local storage (if file not exist) and give local storage path to Glide.

So if file saved once into local storage then directly used it instead of again write file.

It will increase performance.

Comment: We try to used Coroutine(with io thread) with convert base64 to bitmap its working on but on time to load in Glide(main thread) it lag again, (local storage we can't do it bcz some other things also connected with it so its causes issue in this case)

Comment: Glide also loading image in separate thread (Not main thread), if lag then must be some process happening on main thread.

Comment: how I can identify this lag issue?, I load on main thread bcz of after convert successfully to Bitmap view show need it

Comment: Show me your adapter code, if I can find something

Comment: Try **val productImage = imgString.convertBitMap()** inside **withContext** method

Comment: Still lag then try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315733/624069

Comment: will try and let you know. thank you